# How to reduce three.js CPU/GPU usage in browser

Tags: performance, typescript, three.js, webgl, gpu

At the moment I have an animated globe which rotates and the the dots on the globe randomly change colour. It works fine but if left in the background it slows down my laptop a lot. Are there any changes I could make that would reduce how much memory it is using?

In the task manager on chrome I can see it's using 12% CPU and 128MB of GPU memory when the tab is active. Is that normal for three.js or does the code need to be changed?

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(this.enabled) {
        this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
        this.controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
        this.controls.enableDamping = true;
        this.controls.dampingFactor = 0.5;
        this.controls.rotationSpeed = 0.3;
        this.controls.enableZoom = false;
        this.controls.autoRotate = true;
        this.controls.autoRotateSpeed = -1;

        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.rendererContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        this.animate();
        const timerId = setInterval(() => this.updateColor(), 650);
    }
}

private get enabled(): boolean {
    if(this._enabled!==undefined) {
        return this._enabled;
    }
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    this._enabled = gl && gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext;
    return this._enabled;
}

private initGlobe(): void {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 5, 15);
    this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    this.renderer.setClearColor('rgb(55, 44, 80)');

    this.geom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(6, 350, 90);
    this.colors = [];

    this.color = new THREE.Color();
    this.colorList = ['rgb(123, 120, 194)'];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.geom.attributes.position.count; i++) {
        this.color.set(this.colorList[THREE.Math.randInt(0, this.colorList.length - 1)]);
        this.color.toArray(this.colors, i * 3);
    }
    this.geom.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(this.colors), 3));
    this.geom.addAttribute('colorRestore', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(this.colors), 3));

    this.loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    this.loader.setCrossOrigin('');
    this.texture = this.loader.load('/assets/globe-dot.jpg');
    this.texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    this.texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    this.texture.repeat.set(1, 1);
    const oval = this.loader.load('/assets/circle.png');

    this.points = new THREE.Points(this.geom, new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        uniforms: {
            visibility: {
                value: this.texture
            },
            shift: {
                value: 0
            },
            shape: {
                value: oval
            },
            size: {
                value: 0.4
            },
            scale: {
                value: 300
            }
        },
        vertexShader: `
              uniform float scale;
              uniform float size;

              varying vec2 vUv;
              varying vec3 vColor;

              void main() {

                vUv = uv;
                vColor = color;
                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 0.99 );
                gl_PointSize = size * ( scale / length( mvPosition.xyz )) * (0.3 + sin(uv.y * 3.1415926) * 0.35 );
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

              }
        //   `,
        fragmentShader: `
              uniform sampler2D visibility;
              uniform float shift;
              uniform sampler2D shape;

              varying vec2 vUv;
              varying vec3 vColor;

              void main() {

                vec2 uv = vUv;
                uv.x += shift;
                vec4 v = texture2D(visibility, uv);
                if (length(v.rgb) > 1.0) discard;

                gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 0.9 );
                vec4 shapeData = texture2D( shape, gl_PointCoord );
                if (shapeData.a < 0.0625) discard;
                gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * shapeData;
              }
          `,
        transparent: false
    }));

    this.points.sizeAttenuation = false;
    this.scene.add(this.points);

    this.globe = new THREE.Mesh(this.geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'rgb(65, 54, 88)', transparent: true, opacity: 0.5
    }));
    this.globe.scale.setScalar(0.99);
    this.points.add(this.globe);
    this.scene.add(this.globe);
}

animate() {
    this.controls.update();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.animationQueue.push(this.animate);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => this.nextAnimation());

}

nextAnimation() {
    try {
        const animation = this.animationQueue.shift();
        if (animation instanceof Function) {
            animation.bind(this)();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

updateColor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.usedIndices.length; i++) {
        let idx = this.usedIndices[i];
        this.geom.attributes.color.copyAt(idx, this.geom.attributes.colorRestore, idx);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.pointsUsed; i++) {
        let idx = THREE.Math.randInt(0, this.geom.attributes.color.count - 1);
            if (idx%5 == 0 && idx%1 == 0)  {
                this.geom.attributes.color.setXYZ(idx, 0.9, 0.3, 0);
            }
            else {
                this.geom.attributes.color.setXYZ(idx, 1, 1, 1);
            }
        this.usedIndices[i] = idx;
    }

    this.geom.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
```

I looked at other questions which suggest merging the meshes but I'm not sure that would work here. Thanks!

Comment: Judging by the code you posted it looks as good as it can be. Not sure about where the points are actually created, how many there are and how big they are rendered. If you're looking for options to stop all computations when the browser is invisible, look at the visibility-api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API (this will only work when switching to another tab which also rate-limits the animation-loop, having the browser-window in the background counts as "visible")

Comment: FWIW, [this VERY simple example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors) uses 11% CPU and 126MB GPU on my laptop, so I'd agree with Martin, you're probably near 99% efficiency. @MartinSchuhfuß I believe it's not actual `Points`, but "dots" as defined by the texture, which change color controlled by the vertex colors.

Comment: I have to say the code in `nextAnimation(){}` looks very suspect. Do you need to manipulate the array and bind functions 60 times per second? Why do you need a `try catch` ? Is this from the official docs?

Comment: Do you actually need the colors to be random, or will they eventually be set to actual data? You can reduce bandwidth significantly by randomizing colors in the vertex shader instead.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "background"

If by "background" you mean "not the front tab" then, if you're using `requestAnimationFrame` (which you are) then if your page is not the front tab of the browser or if you minimize the browser window the browser will stop sending you *animation frame* events and your page should stop completely.

If by "background" you mean the front tab but of a window that's not minimized and is also not the front window then you can use the `blur` and `focus` events to stop the page completely.

Example: **NOTE: blur events don't seem to work in an iframe so it won't work in the snippet below but if you copy it to a file it should work**

```js
let requestId;

function start() {
  if (!requestId) {
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
}

function stop() {
console.log('stop');
  if (requestId) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
    requestId = undefined;
  }
}

const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');

function animate(time) { 
  requestId = undefined;
  
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(
    150 + 150 * Math.cos(time * 0.001), 
     75 +  75 * Math.sin(time * 0.003),
  );
  ctx.scale(
     Math.cos(time * 0.005), 
     Math.cos(time * 0.007),
  );
  ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${time % 360},100%,50%)`;
  ctx.fillRect(-50, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.restore();
  
  start();
}

start();

window.addEventListener('blur', stop);
window.addEventListener('focus', start);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Of course rather than stopping completely on `blur` you could throttle your app your self. Only render every 5th frame or render less things, etc...

Comment: Thanks for this, Yep so by background I mean not the active tab. Even when i'm on another tab it is still using about the same GPU which doesn't make sense because I assumed the requestAnimationFrame would stop so it would hardly be using any power?